# Route configuration in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am doing code refactoring.

There seems to be a problem while trying to write efficient code by separating the api function.

- controller/board/api.js

```
const add = function (req, res) { 
  if(req.session.user){
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/board/add.ejs');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
};

module.exports = {
  add
};
```

- controller/board/board.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const api = require('./api.js');

app.get('/add', api.add);

module.exports = app;
```

- index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const board = require('./controller/board/board.js');

app.use('/board', board);
```

http://localhost:3000/add
Why Cannot GET /add ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hooking up your router to `/board` so the URL that will be active from `board.js` is `/board/add`, not just `/add`.

Inside of `board.js`, you create a router, add a `/add` route to it and export it (please call it `router`, not `app` since that's what it is).

Then, in `index.js`, you hook up that router with:

```
app.use('/board', board);
```

That means that only routes that start with `/board` will go to your `board` router.  Therefore, to hit your `/add` route, you need a URL of `/board/add`.

If you want `/add` to be active, then either define the `/add` route on the top level `app` object (not on the router) or change to:

```
app.use(board);
```

So, the board router can receive top level routes.

---

FYI, it looks like this might also have problems:

```
res.render(__dirname + '/views/board/add.ejs');
```

because `__dirname` here will be `controller/board`.  So, unless your `/views/board/add.js` is actually inside of `controller/board` as `controller/board/views/board/add.js`, this won't work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for catching errors in places I didn't even think of.
Thanks to you, I found the direction!
Have a nice day! Thank you very much.